# MySQL server-id reset in CentOS

Tags: mysql-5.7, percona-server

I am running MySQL 5.7 (Percona) on CentOS 7.5.x, and when I set the serser-id the config file, MySQL is somehow changing the server-id value to '4294967295'. This is happening on all my PXC nodes. On the slaves, it is resetting to =0. Is this behavior normal? The MySQL config file is located here:

```
/etc/percona-xtradb-cluster.conf.d/mysqld.cnf
```

and the config file looks something like this:

```
...
userstat
#5.7 add setting
table_open_cache = 4096
innodb_open_files = 10240
open_files_limit = 10240
connect_timeout = 60
thread_cache_size = 4096
sql_mode = NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
query_cache_size = 0
slave_pending_jobs_size_max = 32M
range_optimizer_max_mem_size = 8M
log_timestamps = SYSTEM
server-id = 1015111
```

I have installed and managed MySQL on Ubuntu and never experienced this. How can i stop this from happening?